# How many SVM models do I get through running a SVM on cluster of Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, svm, apache-spark-mllib

Can somebody tell me how many models do I get when I run an SVM algorithm on  a cluster which consisting of 3 machines? 
I mean do I get a model for each machine or I get one general model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm trying to understand what do you mean by **SVM models** ?

Comment: for example, consider if i want to run SVM algorithms with MapReduce programming, then I have a SVM model or supported vector foe each of my maps, then i reuse them to one model. i want to know does it appear in Spark or not? what is the output of running SVM on cluster of machines? one model?

Comment: spark will handle the complexity of maintaining the availability of model in each worker machine.

Comment: so when i run a SVM algorithm on 100 partitions of data in cluster of machines, at the end i will get ONE SVM model?

Answer (score 2):

> **Do I get a model for each machine or I get one general model?**

Spark brings the model to worker machines, But **developer will get control as it's running on the single machine**.

> **When I run an SVM algorithm on 100 partitions of data in a cluster of  machines, at the end I will get ONE SVM model?**

Yes, you will get as one model. But it will get executed/processed in 100 executers.

Comment: Thanks So much for your helpful comment :)

Comment: @marjan: let me know if any clarifications needed or consider accepting the answer if the question is addressed.

Comment: Thanks no clarification is needed. I got the answer:)